# common variable for all vertices

Tags: opengl, glsl

is it possible to maintain a single variable for all vertices in vertices in vertex shader.
I mean updation of variable while accessing first vertex should reflect while accessing second vertex....

Comment: _updation_? hahaha (no offense)

Comment: So what you want is to have many vertices all having the same data? So when you change one, all of them change? If so, may I ask what's the point?

Comment: There's uniforms, which are... uniform across all vertices, but you have to set them from outside the shader. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this sounds like a fishy way to do it, and you might want a geometry shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to think of vertex shaders is that all the shaders for all the vertexes run more or less simultaneously, at least to the extent that the hardware can support it.

So the whole idea of "updating a variable while accessing the first vertex should reflect while accessing the second vertex" makes no sense -- the second vertex may end up being processed before the first vertex.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare uniform variable in your shader like:

```
uniform vec3 lightDir;
```

and then pass the value from C/C++ there:

```
glUseProgram(shader_id)
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(shader_id, "lightDir");
    if(location != -1)glUniform3f(location, x,y,z);
```

Edit:

You can iterate the vertices in geometry shader (loop for gl_VerticesIn), and set per-vertex data. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/geometry-shader-examples/

Comment: "Uniforms are so named because they do not change from one execution of a shader program to the next within a particular rendering call."  If he's trying to update this variable between vertexes, a Uniform won't work for him.

Comment: huh, yep. Not sure what he wants to do, but he can iterate vertices in geometry shader and set some per-vertex data.